# Twincat 3 visualization library not resolved

Tags: twincat

I have a file project copied from the beckhoff pc. When i run the project in my laptop all of the visualization library said not resolved (like system_VisuElemMeter,system_VisuElems,system_VisuElemsSpecialControl and others). And no objects at toolbox menu.
Please help me how to solve it! Thank's

reinstall the visualization library already done.

[library error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nug2UpFttFVRo8SLBlGFoZeqaqqW6MNU/view?usp=drive_link)

[toolbox are empty](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XlzXxjz2oX8m4VzDpEiMUBVv1zpozllB/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Check library versions.

Comment: I had uninstalled the library and reinstal again. But i still have an error. Sorry i'm beginner in twincat 3.

Comment: Can you give me details instruction.... thank's

Comment: Post some images of your libraries interface, errors etc... The libraries versions must match, if you have version X and the project has Y, chances are, it wont work. I am not that experienced with TC visus, usually I had no errora, but opening projects in incompatible versions will cause headaches.

Comment: Add them to the original post so that everyone can see.